# Why are cheaters called 'modders' in GTA: Online?

Tags: terminology, grand-theft-auto-online, cheats

[Cheat programs are used by players a lot in GTA Online](http://goo.gl/NKOTe8) freemode. (Moreover, players reported as cheaters do not seem to be banned/blocked by Rockstar).

I can't understand why people (some of them ingame) call players with cheats "modders". Are these synonymous? Perhaps I'm missing a point.

I can't stand  people asking them to give them money for example. While they:

- Spawn a vehicle, including large airplanes everywhere
- Spawn and "attach" LS Wheel with physics on specific player
- Spawn objects without mesh but with physics model - an amazingly annoying exploit
- Exploding all vehicles and players in session by clicking a button
- Unlimited cash spawn everywhere
- Spawn 100 clones of player at his location (NPC actors)

Cheating appears to be very pervasive in GTA: Online, there are a lot of different cheat programs used by many players, especially in freemode. However, I have noticed that such cheaters are referred to as "modders". Is 'cheating' and 'modding' synonymous? Maybe I do not understand, are these players really "modders" (developers)?

Comment: This is not a forum, but for specific questions and answers. This is way to broad and opinion-based.

Comment: I wouldnt say this is too broad at all the OP is asking about a specific term within the gaming community

Comment: It's pretty clear what's being asked, so it's not unclear. There's a very narrow definition, so it's not broad. As for opinion based, well, in my opinion it isn't :). I don't think it's a good question, but I also don't think it needs to be closed.

Comment: Thanks for edit. You can downvote as long as you want, but there is no actual problem with my question.

Comment: @DmitrijA There is more than one way to cheat in a game. Someone who modifies the game is a modder. If they choose to cheat by modding, they are still a modder. Also, you say players reported as cheaters are not banned, do you have anything to back that up or is it just an opinion based on frustration.

Comment: They can downvote as they like this queation is very valid

Comment: [citation needed] On your first paragraph: Who is to say that Rockstar doesn't do anything to stop them? Maybe they do, maybe they don't, maybe the cheating is systemic enough that even if they fix 100 exploits and ban 10,000 people there's still 1000 more exploits and 100,000 more people using them. Either way it seems irrelevant to the question you are asking here, and might be better if it's removed :)

Comment: For limited ones to find a confirmation, you could just try searching media. https://goo.gl/NKOTe8

Comment: @DmitrijA - Thanks for the link, it makes things clearer. Can I suggest an edit to your question to say *"Cheating appears to be very pervasive in GTA: Online, there are a lot of different cheat programs used by many players, especially in freemode.

However, I have noticed that such cheaters are referred to as "modders". Is 'cheating' and 'modding' synonymous?  

Maybe I do not understand, are these players really "modders" (developers)?"* 

I feel like this would make it clearer

Comment: This is still unclear, to me. "Are they really modders (developers)"? what do you mean? Modders =/= developers. This question comes off as more of a rant than anything else. Would VTC, but apparently having a bounty blocks that. That could be a potential issue..

Comment: *"I reported about 15+ players all with 100% confirmation, some of them are surely reported by other players. None of them banned"* **send them to gtaonlinebanhammer@rockstargames.com**, **everytime** I did this with proof, **they got banned**.

Comment: @DmitrijA - I have removed the parts from your question that specifically attack Rockstar, it's mostly irrelevant to the question '*Are cheaters known as 'modders?'*. If you want to ask *'How to report cheaters?'* you should ask it as a separate question instead. You'll find you will get a better response.

Answer (score 5):

Cheaters, modders and hackers are all likely the same people. The people you see cheating using mods are often not likely the ones making the mods, so to answer your question: modders (as in those who cheat by using mods) are likely **not** developers. Not developers for Rockstar Games, and not developers in general. Typically, the term modders refers to a player who is using a mod or cheat program (likely made by someone else).

In the same sense of the term hackers: It's not uncommon to hear the term "hackers" thrown about in any online game, GTA Online inclusive, even though the term hacker was more to describe a computer enthusiast or one who hacked together programs for fun. [Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hacker_(term)):

> Today, mainstream usage of "hacker" mostly refers to computer criminals, due to the mass media usage of the word since the 1980s. This includes what hacker slang calls "script kiddies," people breaking into computers using programs written by others, with very little knowledge about the way they work. This usage has become so predominant that the general public is unaware that different meanings exist.

Those who use cheat programs in games are coined hackers or modders rather than just cheaters. While I can't find any evidence for this, I would assume it's to point out the exact way they are cheating.

For example, let's say you and I wished to have a race in GTA Online and we decided on some rules; however, I broke those rules within the context of the game (cut corners, took a shortcut, brought along a modified car etc) in order to benefit myself and win, you might call me a cheater.

If instead my car started ignoring gravity, or I was invincible or faster than a car can go by the rules of the game, you would probably consider me a "hacker" or "modder" because I'd be (most definitely) using some kind of program to alter the game.

My advice to you is to simply ignore these people. Don't fuel their twisted sense of fun by typing in chat; instead, report them! I know it might feel like nothing ever happens, but you might as well do everything you can.

[Rockstar have announced](http://www.rockstargames.com/newswire/article/52451/update-targeting-cheaters-in-gta-online) that they are targeting cheaters:

> As part of our ongoing commitment to combat cheating and griefing, we have recently implemented new systems to allow us to more efficiently detect and target any players found running mods and cheat programs within GTA Online.

A [link from the same page details how to report cheaters](https://support.rockstargames.com/hc/en-us/articles/200704406-How-to-Report-Cheaters-in-Grand-Theft-Auto-Online):

> 1. Pause the game and navigate to the “ONLINE” tab.
> 2. Select “Players”, and choose the name of the player cheating.
> 3. Select “Report”, and confirm your report with the “Exploit” category.

Rockstar suggests that this is the best way to report cheaters, rather than forums etc:

> The best and most effective way to report cheaters in GTA Online is through the in-game menu. When reports are sent to us via the in-game tools, we are able to study much more data to help identify and act on the user and the activity in question

It is also possible kick players from the same menu you use to report them. I can't find numbers confirmation, but a few votes from players on the server should at least kick the offending player from the server.

Comment: "Select “Players”, and choose the name of the player cheating. " The problem is a lot of the time you know that there is a modder causing trouble in the session but you don't know who is doing it.

Answer (score 4):

They are given the term modders because they are modifying the game.

Technically anything rockstar develops or any other company in the software development industry infact, the developers themselves are modders because they are making a modification to the game.

Modder just means modifier because they are doing something to modify something.

Comment: Hmm, whilst I agree in general, I wouldn't call the development team 'modders', as 'modding' implies changing what is already there, whereas they are developing the base game. Perhaps the team working on new content (DLC) or on Support (Bug fixes) could be called 'modders', but even that's a bit of a stretch. :)

Comment: @Robotnik I'm a former mod/hack/cheat/whatever developer for GTA V (not online), we used to inject codes, modify the game memory, the game natives etc. The hacks/cheats were installed in the same way as other mods, hence they might be called modders. I think that the term was coined back in gta v's console-only times as it required you to modify the game files and sometimes the console os to make it accept the modded game files.

Comment: You didn't hack dude, you modded, there is a clear line between them @ardaozkal

Comment: @Foxhound people used to call us hack developers (for ex. I never added online check to my mod as it was [open source](https://github.com/ardaozkal/YoloNet-GTAV)) so yeah, that's why I stated hack too.

Comment: By hacking something you're gaining access to something that is protected. That's not modding that's hacking, users called us 'hackers' but we weren't hacking, as for online check/open source that has nothing to do with whether something is a hack or mod

Comment: @Foxhound - ironically enough, 'Hacking' used to be synonymous with 'Programming', such that a 'Hacker' was simply 'one who codes programs'. It wasn't until the first few major cybercrime attacks that 'hacker' started to be used more for the 'cyber criminal' meaning.

Comment: @Foxhound There are multiple meanings of hacking. Some of which have absolutely nothing to do with programming.